# How to get data attribute from HTML option value, and parse into integer, using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to build a nutrition calculator, and this is just a very very basic start to my code. I am trying to figure out how to have more than one value for each dropdown select option. I am using data-attributes to do this. For example, in my code below, the "original" option is "value = 5 data-fat = 13" meaning there are 5 calories and 13 grams of fat. I am trying to parse these integers out using javascript. My code below functions, but it only prints the calories, and it doesn't print it as an integer. Please send any advice you can! I am new to coding in javascript :P

```
<body>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#base").change(function() {
        var cntrol = $(this);
        var calories = cntrol.val();
        var fat = $(this).data('fat');

$("#calculate").click(function(){
        $('#FinalFat').text(fat);
        $('#FinalCal').text(calories);
});
});
});
    
<form id="customizations">
<label for="base">Base:</label>
<select name="base" id="base">
        <option> --- </option>
        <option value="5" data-fat:"13">Original</option>
        <option value="4" data-fat:"10">Cold Brew</option>
        <option value="2" data-fat:"23">Sunrise</option>
        <option value="12" data-fat:"3">Midnight</option>
        <option value="4" data-fat:"13">Decaf</option>
</select>
</form>

<div class="column">
<button id="calculate"> Calculate Nutrition </button>
      
<p>Fat:<label id="FinalFat" style="color:green"></label></p>
<p>Calories:<label id="FinalCal" style="color:red"></label></p>
      
</div>
```

Comment: `data-fat:"13"` is not valid HTML. `data-fat="13"` is.

Comment: You also have forgot to close the script tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change attribute `data-fat:"13"` to `data-fat="13"` first, then you can use this to get integer

```
var fat = $(this).data('fat');
fat = parseInt(fat);
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the value of the attribute using jQuery, use the ".attr()" method:

```
var fat = $(this).attr('data-fat');
```

And in order to parse your results to int, just use javascript's native function "parseInt()"

```
fat = parseInt(fat)
```